# Import multiple multivariate time-series csv-files

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, time-series

I would like to do an anomaly detection with LSTM. However, I have not yet worked with time-series. I would like to work step by step.

My concrete question is first how I have to prepare my data to be able to work with it later. I have several csv-files. In each csv file the temperature and pressure of a machine is recorded for about 1 to 2 minutes. The sampling rate is about 200ms, but can vary minimally.

For Example:

Machine_1_Cycle_1.csv:

```
time temp pres
06:34:20,343      98          3
06:34:20,541      99          3.1
06:34:20,749      100         3.3
06:34:20,942      110         3.6
06:34:21,205      111         3.8
```

Machine_2_Cycle_1.csv:

```
time temp pres
07:12:15,262      87           2.8
07:12:15,481      88           3.0
07:12:15,707      89           3.4
```

Machine_2_cycle_2.csv:

```
time temp temp_2 pres
12:59:22,547      85     77      3.2
12:59:22,746      87     73      3.5
12:59:22,948      89     71      3.7
```

What you can see is that the timestamps are not exactly 200ms apart. Also, the number of data points per file varies. It also happens that there are additional features in a file that are not needed.

Q1: I want to plot the curves, e.g. of the temperature, in one chart. Do I have to convert the timestamps to relative time so that all files start at 0?

Q2: How do I import the files to work with them later? Do I have to create a list in which all cycles of all machines are concatenated? Or do I make a multidimensional dataframe? (remember: the files have different line numbers)

Q3: Do I have to create two new columns in which I write the machine number and the cycle number? For example:

Machine_2_cycle_2.csv:

```
time temp pres machine_nr cycle_nr
12:59:22,547      85           3.2          2             2
12:59:22,746      87           3.5          2             2
12:59:22,948      89           3.7          2             2
```

Or how can I filter later for a specific machine and a specific cycle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a tab delimited file format, or you have copy-pasted values from Excel.

If you are using a comma delimited file format your file should look like this:

```
time,temp,pres
"07:12:15,262",87,2.8
"07:12:15,481",88,3.0
"07:12:15,707",89,3.4
```

In this case, you can use Python's native csv module to parse the information into a list or dictionary. For example:

```
import csv

# list csv files to ingest
files = [
    'Machine_1_Cycle_1.csv',
    'Machine_1_Cycle_2.csv',
    'Machine_2_Cycle_1.csv',
    'Machine_2_Cycle_2.csv',
]

# create list to fill with all data
data = []

for f in files:

    # get machine & cycle numbers
    # requires proper naming convention
    machine = f.split('_')[1]
    cycle = f.split('_')[3][:-4] 

    with open(f, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        
        # skip csv header
        next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(machine)
            row.append(cycle)
            data.append(row)
```

Be aware that all rows are represented as lists of strings. You can set the desired data type within the for-loop, or later on when you will use the data for visualization.